# build running automatically in gitlab

Tags: deployment, build, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have installed GitLab in Ubuntu 18.04 and moved it over to Apache. When I create a new project, with the initial commit (or any commit after) it tries to run a build. Of course this isn't going to work, as there are no build scripts available, and I never want it to build on commit, I want to create my own script to deploy the project on demand. So the questions:

1) How do I stop a new project trying to build?

2) If a commit fails, how do I clear the error in the main projects page?? (its a commit fail error)

3) In the GitLab web interface, how can I have a button to start a build/deploy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Possible Scenario why auto build starts:

1. You have a .gitlab-ci.yml file in your repository root
2. You have turned on AutoDevOps for your project/group/everything...

2) No Way, Although You can skip or run build on specific branch only

3) Gitlab has a option to run jobs manually. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#when-manual. It will give a button on WebUI.

Comment: I am creating a new repo and its running the build on creation, so there is no yml, just the blank readme. I don't see any option to turn it on or off for the project, or for the group and as far as I can tell its off globally. Where would these settings be?

Comment: @MicWit can you lookup Project Settings -> CI/CD -> Auto DevOps. If the "Enable AutoDevops" radio button is selected than this can happen. Or Admin Area->Settings->Continuous Integration and Deployment->Enabled Auto DevOps for projects by default is turned on some how

Answer (score 1):

On 1), it might be GitLab's [Auto Devops](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/) being enabled automatically.

If you do not use CI on your project, you should probably consider doing it. In any case, you can disable it globally:

1. Log in as `root` on your GitLab instance
2. Go to <kbd>Admin Area</kbd> > <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Continuous Integration and Deployment</kbd>
3. Click the <kbd>Expand</kbd> button
4. Untick <kbd>Default to Auto DevOps pipeline for all projects</kbd>

I have not tried this myself, but quoting community member [Stayen](https://forum.gitlab.com/u/stayen/) on the GitLab forum, you can also disable CI on a single project basis:

> To disable per a single project, as far as I know, disabling Pipelines from “Settings > CI” works as well.

See these posts at the [GitLab Forum](https://forum.gitlab.com) for more context:

- https://forum.gitlab.com/t/pipeline-nnn-has-failed-for-master-how-to-disable-ci-for-a-project/19683
- https://forum.gitlab.com/t/should-auto-devops-be-disabled-by-default/19631
- https://forum.gitlab.com/t/autodevops-running-automatically/19626/2

Answer (score 1):

For a specific stage you can include manual activity as in below example:

```
deploy_job:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - make deploy
  when: manual
```